# How do I loop code that contains multiple functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

I am designing a program that calculates your paycheck. It involves multiple functions and what I need to do is loop all of these functions from the order in which they are called. Here is my code without loops:

```
def showIntro():
    intro = print('Hello! I will take your input and calculate your 
weekly paycheck before 
taxes.')

showIntro()

def get_rate():
    rate = float(input('Enter hourly rate: '))
    return rate

def get_hours():
    hours = float(input('Enter hours worked: '))
    if hours >= 41:
        print('Your base hours including overtime is: ' , hours)
    if hours <= 40:
        print('Your hours entered were: ' , hours)
    return hours

def get_paycheck(rate , hours):
    paycheck = rate  * hours
    if hours >= 41:
        print('Your weekly paycheck with over time is: ' , rate * hours)
    if hours <=40:
        print('Your weekly paycheck is: ' , rate * hours)
    return (rate , hours)

rate = get_rate()
hours = get_hours()

get_paycheck(rate,hours)
```

end code

How do I loop this so it goes back to showIntro() and repeats itself.

Comment: Learn about for & while loops: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm

Comment: Give it a shot to read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all function calls inside a `while` loop.

```
while True: # or some other condition
    showIntro()
    rate = get_rate()
    hours = get_hours()
    get_paycheck(rate, hours)
```